# SQl2008 Compatibilty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Database in the sql2000 can i use the features of sql2008 without changing compatibility level ?

Can i use reporting services with the database of sql2000  without change compatibility level?

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a link, but I read (on MSDN) yesterday (or the day before) that reporting services needs level 90.

I have no idea what this really means, or if it works on SQL2000.

I just read it, and thought I'll transfer the knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the newer SQL 2008 features will not work on a database on compat mode 80. Check the details in Books Online in the section 'Compatibility level', there's more details there.

Why don't you want to change compat mode?